# Adding Equation number to multline* equation

Tags: equations, numbering, counters, multline

Currently my report has multiple equations, some of which require using the multline function. Is there a way to continue the equation numbering used when using {equation} on to equations using {multline*}?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I'm not sure if I've understood how you use `multline*` environments at present. At any rate, `multline` (*with* the `*`/asterisk) environments are numbered, just as `equation` environments are numbered. For more information on how the various multi-line display math environments of the `amsmath` package -- among them `gather`, `align`, `aligned`, and `multline` -- may be used, do consult the package's user guide. Create a command prompt and type `texdoc amsmath` to open the user guide in a pdf viewer.

Comment: You might also look up \tag.